# Replace kotlins default coroutine dispatcher on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using the google app engine standard environment and I am looking for a way to replace the default `kotlinx.couroutine.Dispatchers` (`IO`, `.Default` and `.Main`) by custom dispatchers. This is necessary because each thread which is created on the app engine must be created by a special thread factory: `com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()`. With this `ThreadFactory` I am able to create a `Dispatcher`:

```
val threadFactory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()
val numberOfThreads = 2
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads, threadFactory)
val coroutineDispatcher = executorService.asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

But I am not able to replace the default dispatchers. Is there a way or another solution for this?

Comment: Very probably not, except maybe by hacking with reflection. Are you forced to use the built-in dispatchers?

Comment: Default dispatchers are long-lived, while here you are creating threads only in the scope of the current request. A better solution would would be to implement your own request-scoped dispatchers if needed. Why do you even need those additional threads? You can just call `runBlocking { ... }` in your requests and run multiple concurrent operations in the scope of your request using the original request thread.

Comment: I need the additional threads because the app engine must use  `java.net.URL`s blocking connection to issue a request (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests). If I must do multiple request in parallel there is no other option than using multiple threads under the hood. Is it not? Probably I should implement your suggested approach of the request-scoped dispatcher.